# How to get users accounts (pages) description using one Facebook API call?

Tags: javascript, java, ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

When I want to users description of the pages in facebook:

- First of all using graphPath: **me/accounts** (It returns only IDs of pages)
- Second by using [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) API call getting description field.

In this scenario I need to execute several API call to for getting description of the page.

My question is here a way to get pages description with one Facebook API request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the API call: `/me/accounts?fields=id,name,description`

Example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cdescription&version=v2.11

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how would be possible to get email address of me/accounts?

Comment: /me/accounts?fields=id,name,description,emails